# Laravel 5.6 and Amazon S3 [InvalidArgumentException]

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am currently setting up **Amazon S3 storage** with my website built on **Laravel 5.6.11.** 
I set up the env variables in ***filesystems.php*** file as it

```
   's3' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key' => env('AKIAJ_MY_KEY_BWVRHQ'),
        'secret' => env('2IUTHoHg3_MY_SECRET_K5Rs'),
        'region' => env('eu-central-1'),
        'bucket' => env('my-storage'),
    ],`
```

Afterwards, I wanted to test the connection between the website and S3 with ***php artisan tinker*** but when I simply try to connect to Amazon S3 with `Storage::disk('s3')->files`,

It shows me this error

> **InvalidArgumentException with message 'Missing required client configuration options:  region: (string)   A "region" configuration
>   value is required for the "s3" service   (e.g., "us-west-2"). A list
>   of available public regions and endpoints can be   found at
>   http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html.'**

I have already tried several things like reloading ***php artisan tinker*** or ***php artisan config:clear*** but it is not working.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

```
env('eu-central-1')
```

That is looking for an environment variable called `eu-central-1`.  You probably want to set it up more like this:

in .env:

```
AWS_REGION=eu-central-1
```

in filesystems.php:

```
'region' => env('AWS_REGION')
```

Or just

```
'region' => 'eu-central-1'
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer.
I tried to but have another error

PHP Notice:  Undefined property: Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemAdapter::$files on line 1

Comment: That is because `Storage::disk('s3')->files` is not right - `files` is not a property there.  What are you trying to accomplish?  Check out https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem#retrieving-files

Comment: Storage::disk('s3')->files retrieves the list of stored files but even if I try something like Storage::disk('s3')->exists('file.jpg'); I have the same error.

Comment: If you are trying to put file on S3 simply use Storage::disk('s3')->put('destination_path','your_file_content')

Answer (score 2):

Also don't forget to clear config cache, when you doing changes like this.

```
$ artisan config:clear
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jeff, in fact it was the whole code that was wrong.

I had to remove all env() tags as you mentioned above.

```
's3' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key' => 'AKIAJ_MY_KEY_BWVRHQ',
        'secret' => '2IUTHoHg3_MY_SECRET_K5Rs',
        'region' => 'eu-central-1',
        'bucket' => 'my-storage',
 ]
```